# "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" on Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-8

I'm trying to create a new table for my database. 

I previously created a table (tipo) with a PK (IdCorso), then another table(corsoscii) with a foreign key associated with tipo.

When I execute the artisan command for corsoscii 
 `php artisan migrate --path='./database/migrations/2021_02_23_155544_create_corsoscii_table.php'` it gives me this error:

```
("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table impianto_scii.corsoscii (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")
```

This is the setup code for "tipo"

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tipo', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('idCorso');
            $table->string('descrizione');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

...and for "corsoscii"

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('corsoscii', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('idCorso');
        $table->integer('tipo');
        $table->string('nome');
        $table->integer('membriMax');
        $table->date('inizio');
        $table->date('fine');
        $table->timestamps();

    });

    Schema::table('corsoscii', function(Blueprint $table){

        $table->foreign('tipo')
            ->references('idCorso')->on('tipo')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        
        $table->primary('idCorso');
    });
}
```

I'm a neophyte with Laravel, any advice is welcome.

Comment: I think `$table->integer('tipo');` should be `$table->integer('tipo')->unsigned();` to match the same data type

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not very accurate, keeps returning the same error? It's your db engine InnoDB?

Comment: The same error occurs. Yes, my db engine is InnoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first please run

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

then delete "corsoscii" table. then try these changes.

```
Schema::create('corsoscii', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('idCorso');
            $table->integer('tipo')->unsigned();;
            $table->string('nome');
            $table->integer('membriMax');
            $table->date('inizio');
            $table->date('fine');
            $table->timestamps();

        });

        Schema::table('corsoscii', function(Blueprint $table){

            $table->foreign('tipo')
                  ->references('idCorso')->on('tipo')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

first try unsigned() for tipo and then idCorso is already primary key when you will use increments() method. then run

```
php artisan migrate
```

this will work fine. i tried that.

Answer (score 3):

`$table->integer('tipo');` needs to match *exactly* the field it is a foreign key for.

`$table->increments('idCorso');` generates an `unsignedInteger`, so that's what it should be.

```
$table->unsignedInteger('tipo');
```

If your migration uses `bigIncrements`, you need to use:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('tipo');
```

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ You're right, my apologies. Laravel now creates new migrations with `bigIncrements` by default hence my confusion. Updated the answer.